# Billing Provider - Pay What You Want

Tags: currency, billing, activemerchant, in-app-billing

I have an app that needs to use with a pay what you want model. I'm struggling to find a billing provider that offers this service outside of donate buttons.

The app is for a for-profit company, so I'm not sure if there is any gray area using Paypal, Amazon or Google for this. Outside of Paypal's 'donate' button, the process of allowing users to enter in a value they'd like to pay seems clunky at best.

I was wondering if there were any less known billing providers out there that offer a simple a nice pay-what-you-want or pay-as-you-will option. Merchant accounts and gateways arn't an issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The possible isssues are You need to find international payment provider, User needs credit card.In case You use local payment system like netbanking you can target bigger circle.

For International payment Options are
http://www.wilsonweb.com/wct4/international.cfm
http://hubpages.com/hub/The-Top-International-Payment-Methods

Answer (score 0):

Why not just implement it yourself, just like any other shopping cart app? The difference being that instead of the "cart" calculating the total for the user to pay, the user himself fills up the amount in a form. After that, just redirect him to the credit card processor with whatever amount he filled up!